# Is there a way to download uploaded files on server from the CKeditor itself?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and it has File Browser plugin which allow to upload files from locale directory to server. It also provide browse option which basically list out all the files on server like below
[image]

I basically want to allow users to download these files using ckeditor, is there a plugin or script that can be used?

Answer (score -1):

This should help. The plugin works with CKEditor 3.6 and 4.x, the only requirement is that you have already configured CKEditor to allow file uploads.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/simpleuploads

Comment: The question is for downloading content.